# I renamed aspx file name but now i can't reach to controls from cs file

Tags: asp.net

I renamed aspx file name but now i can't reach to controls from cs file.
I deleted designer.cs file and created by right click on aspx file with Convert To Web Application. But still can't find controls while i press Ctrl+Space (code intellisense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the `CodeBehind` property in the `@Page` directive points to the `.cs` file, and that the `Inherits` property points to the correct class name in the `.cs` file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check codebehind property as well as inherieted property that must be the class that you have defined in .cs file